# Why the other blade doesn' appear in another page ? Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

i try it with ohter buttons and it works but this one idk what happen !! the problem is when i click the button `reserve` it show up the same page and i want the code inside `reservedone.blade.php` to appear

my routes code :

```
 Route::get('/reserve1_view',[UserController::class,'addview']);

Route::get('/reserve2_view',[UserController::class,'addview2']);

Route::get('/reserve_done',[UserController::class,'reservedone1']);


Route::post('/reserveinfo',[UserController::class,'reserveinfo']);
```

Controller code :

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function addview(){
        return view('user.reserve1');
    }

    public function addview2(){
        return view('user.reserve2');
    }

    public function reservedone1(){
        return view('user.reservedone');
    }


    public function reserveinfo(Request $request){

        $data = new reserveinfo;
        $data->male=$request->Male;
        $data->female=$request->female;

        $data->fullname=$request->fullname;
        $data->email=$request->email;
        $data->birthday=$request->date;


        $test_pcr=$request->file('testpcr');
        $imagename=time().'.'.$test_pcr->getClientoriginalExtension();
        $request->testpcr->move('Text-PCR-of-users',$imagename);
        $data->test_pcr=$imagename;

        $Doctor_prescription=$request->file('doctorpres');
        $imagename2=time().'.'.$Doctor_prescription->getClientoriginalExtension();
        $request->doctorpres->move('Doctor-prescription-of-users',$imagename2);
        $data->Doctor_prescription=$imagename2; 

        if(Auth::id()){
            $data->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
        }
        $data->save();
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    
}
```

blade :

```
  <!--##########  Send request ########## -->
                <div class="Reserve">
                    <a href="{{url('reserve_done')}}">
                        <button>Reserve</button>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try executing in your shell:

```html
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan optimize
php artisan view:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

then reload the page, if the problem persists let me know

Comment: i try to execute what you tell me but nothing happen the problem didn't solved :(